# Upgrade 14 to 16.04: required dependency 'dpkg (>= 1.17.5ubuntu5.6)' is not installed. Help?

Tags: upgrade, dpkg

I am trying to update my Ubuntu from 14 to the latest Ubuntu 16.04. I am not able to upgrade and the following error messages comes up. What should I do?

required dependency 'dpkg (>= 1.17.5ubuntu5.6)' is not installed.

Answer (score 7):

Update the dpkg using the following steps:

Step 1.

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb
```

OR (Depending on your system)

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.6_i386.deb
```

Step 2.

```
sudo dpkg -i dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb
```

OR

```
sudo dpkg -i dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.6_i386.deb
```

Then trigger the update again by:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```